"Close as Off topic" statement is incorrect
The current "Close as off-topic" description reads:

Questions on LEGO® - Stack Exchange are expected to generally relate to LEGOs, within the scope defined in the faq.

As per the official LEGO Group fair play guidelines:

Proper Use of the LEGO Trademark on a Web Site
  If the LEGO trademark is used at all, it should always be used as an adjective, not as a noun. For example, say "MODELS BUILT OF LEGO BRICKS". Never say "MODELS BUILT OF LEGOs".

Can we change the Close as Off topic statement to:

Questions on LEGO® - Stack Exchange are expected to generally relate to LEGO Bricks, within the scope defined in the faq.

Alternatively, we could make it more general:

Questions on LEGO® - Stack Exchange are expected to generally relate to brick building toys, within the scope defined in the faq.

Note also that the guidelines state:

[I]mproper use of the LEGO trademark cannot be made proper by including a disclaimer.

Regardless of whether it reads better or not, LEGO group want it written as an adjective rather than a noun, so on core site furniture we should respect that. I'm not calling for editors to go around changing everyone's questions and answers to the correct form, although someone else might.

Ooh, this is covered in the trademark usage guidelines. Good to know.

@JoeWreschnig But if their extreme paranoia results in us getting shut down because we didn't follow their guidelines, that would be a shame :(

@JoeWreschnig Heh. If we ever meet up, I'd love to buy you a beer or three (or your preferred beverage of choice). :D

This has been changed to read "LEGO Bricks", thanks!

